# Some Fonts don't appear in LibreOffice

Tags: fonts, libreoffice, fontconfig

I installed some fonts (mingliu.ttc) by putting them in ~/.fonts/

The font is visible in other applications (such as Abiword & Firefox).

But it does not appear in the font menu of LibreOffice.
When I type the font name manually, the characters display as squares.

How can I install the font for LibreOffice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's weird.  I just tried with the same font (mingliu.ttc) and it worked fine in LibreOffice on Ubuntu 10.10.

There might be a problem with your font cache.

Try running `sudo fc-cache -f -v`.  This will rebuild the cache.

Comment: I deleted ~/.fontconfig manually and run fc-cache again.It works now.

Comment: If you use the "Quick Start" feature (the LibreOffice's tray icon), you should exit from there (right click on the icon -> Terminate QuickStart) after closing all open documents, and then rebuild the cache, otherwise LibreOffice won't update its internal cache and you won't see the new fonts.

Comment: 11 years later and this still helped me (Linux Mint). One thing is that running it with sudo clears the root's font cache, so to clear my local cache (which is where my fonts were installed to) I had to run it without sudo: `fc-cache -f -v` It works now - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My version of libreoffice does not "see" True Type Collection (.ttc) fonts. So I had to break open the collection like this:
1. install Fontforge through the Ubuntu Software app.
2. right click the .ttc file and open with Fontforge.
3. you will be asked to choose which of the fonts in the collection you want to choose, pick anyone.
4. next step select "Generate fonts" and in the drop down menu select True Type and save. You wil get a .ttf
5. start again to convert the other members of the collection and then install them all the normal way and they do appear in libreoffice (as one)

Answer (score 0):

I tried some methods, but all do not work for me.
I finally manually downloaded the fonts and move them to `~/.local/share/fonts/`, and `sudo fc-cache -f -v` to refresh the cache.